# ASP.NET Core error on unsuccessful formatting responding in json instead of xml

Tags: asp.net-core-6.0

For requests that make it into the Post function that I can control, I do this:

```
return new ContentResult
{
  Content = xmlString,
  ContentType = "application/xml",
  StatusCode = 200
};
```

And it behaves as expected. However, whenever those requests fail to reach that point due to failing at the formatter, this is the closest to the response I am aware of that I can control:

```
private readonly IConfiguration _config;
public customXmlInputFormatter(MvcOptions options) : base(options)
{
  SupportedMediaTypes.Add("application/xml");
}

public customXmlInputFormatter(MvcOptions options, IConfiguration config) : base(options)
{
  SupportedMediaTypes.Add("application/xml");

  _config = config;
}

public override async Task<InputFormatterResult> ReadRequestBodyAsync(InputFormatterContext context)
{
  string xml = await new StreamReader(context.HttpContext.Request.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
  xml = Regex.Replace(xml, "&(?!(amp|apos|quot|lt|gt);)", "&amp;");
  var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(customXML));
  customXML result;
  try
  {
    using (TextReader reader = new StringReader(xml))
    {
      result = (customXML)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
    }

    var ret = InputFormatterResult.Success(result);

    return ret;
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    string payload = $"Error:\n{ex.Message}\n\nInput:\n{xml}";
    Helper.SaveFile("error-log/error-DATETIME.txt", payload);

    result = null;
    var ret = InputFormatterResult.Success(result);
    
    return ret;
  }
}
```

When it fails (when the xml body being sent is improperly formatted), it saves the file as expected but the response comes back as json:

```
{
 "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
 "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
 "status": 400,
 "traceId": "00-long-id-00",
 "errors": {
    "": [
        "The input field is required."
    ]
 }
}
```

And for the headers of the response:

```
Content-Type: application/problem+json; charset=utf-8
```

It seems that this feeds something else which generates (after a bunch of searching) a ProblemDetails response, but how can I tell the application to mirror the content type of the request (in this case XML) or at the very least explicitly send it as problem+xml (since as of the time of this writing, that's the only content type they expect to work)?

Comment: You can refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/handle-errors?view=aspnetcore-7.0)  to set `Content-Type`.